# What's the process to change student Visa to work permit upon graduation in Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany, student-visa, blue-card

I am an MBA student in Germany. My Master's thesis defense is scheduled on 22-Jan and this marks the end of my Master's degree. I have a permanent job offer, exceeding Blue Card threshold, in Berlin with joining date from 1-Feb. I am planning to move to Berlin on 23-Jan, and am already trying to find apartments there. My current student Visa is valid until 28-Feb.

In this situation, can I go to Ausländerbehörde in Berlin, even if I don't have an apartment with Anmeldung yet, for extending Visa and converting it into full-time work permit? What documents, if any, do I need from my University after completing my thesis defense, to prove the completion of Master's degree. As far as I know, actual graduation ceremony happens in April. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until one moved to Berlin, his/her documents are in the immigration office (Ausländerbehörde) of the place where he/she lives. So in such cases, one needs to go to the Ausländerbehörde of the place where he/she is registered. They can actually issue a new card for you, even if the job is in Berlin.

Of course, one could first move to Berlin, register there and go to the Ausländerbehörde in Berlin (which can be more crowded). However, in this case they will probably wait 3-4 extra weeks to have documents transferred from previous Ausländerbehörde. Probably, one can get a Fiktionsbescheinigung, which will prolong the validity of the current card (and student residence permit should allow working for 120 days per year, which is enough for approximately 5-6 months).

For the documents you need, it is better to ask your local Ausländerbehörde, how to do in your situation.